# Highcharts Bubbles - how do I change bubble background and line color?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am trying to change the background and line colors of a bubble series.

At the moment, it is the default blue with dark blue border.  I want the border to be white and the bubble background to be transparent.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Jacques

Answer (score 4):

You can set some of the `plotOptions.bubble`-options to achieve this. Notably:

```
plotOptions: {
    bubble: {
        color: 'white',
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'transparent'
        }
    }
}
```

Here we set the default color to white, and the marker fill color to transparent. Note that this will set the color for all series. If you want to specify it on a series-level you'd just pass the `color` option to each series.

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/39bbLL6q/) of how it looks.

The look and feel of hovering and selecting can be controlled with `plotOptions.bubble.marker.states`. Check [the documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bubble.marker.states) for details.